# image not appending to card

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dom

I cannot get an image (in this case a yelp logo) to append to a text link.

We are pulling from Yelp API and making cards of the results as part of a student project. Everything works great but we though it would look nice to have the link to the business full yelp page be a logo instead of just text.

As the JS was originally written by someone else on the team it just said "visit website" and was clickable to go to the linked yelp page. I thought it would be simple to append the yelp logo and took the issue.

I have tried writing it a few different ways both on my own and from suggestions others have made, and it still only puts out the text (which is a clickable link) but the img does not attach.

```
// website
var websiteURL = response.businesses[i].url
//logo image for yelp
 var logo = imageObject.src = "assets/images/Yelp 
 Burst/Screen/Yelp_burst_positive_RGB.png"

 var cardBody1 = $("<p>")
 var a = $("<a>")                 
 a.attr("href", websiteURL)
 var imgYelp = $("<img>")
 a.attr("src", logo(imgYelp))
 a.html("Visit on" + imgYelp)                                     
 cardBody1.append(a)
```

no error message in console log this way. just no logo. 
Should be " View on  LOGO"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems with this:

1) I don't see anywhere where you append `cardBody1` into the page. You create it, but then it just sits there doing nothing. You need to insert into your page (probably by appending it to an existing element which is already part of the DOM) before anything will show up.

2) Also, despite what you mentioned, as far as I can see the code **will** create a console error - see  http://jsfiddle.net/4qdb3jfe. You define `logo` as a string, and then later try to use it like a function. That makes no sense. Also `<a>` elements don't need a "src" tag. I'm going to assume you meant `imgYelp.attr("src", logo);`, to assign `logo` as the source of the image, instead.

3) `a.html("Visit on" + imgYelp)` also won't work since `imgYelp` is an object - you're concatenating it to a string, which will turn the object into a string, and you'll get this: https://jsfiddle.net/4qdb3jfe/1/ . Two separate appends will do this better.

And once you've sorted all of that, then you'll get somewhere:

```js
// website
var websiteURL = "https://miro.medium.com";
var imageObject = {};
//logo image for yelp
var logo = imageObject.src = "https://miro.medium.com/max/800/0*g3ns8QALNBBH7CBA."

var cardBody1 = $("<p>");
var a = $("<a>");
a.attr("href", websiteURL);
var imgYelp = $("<img>");
imgYelp.attr("src", logo);
a.append("Visit on");
a.append(imgYelp);
cardBody1.append(a);

$("#main").append(cardBody1);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 20px;
}

img {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">

</div>
```